# Query in SQL Server with multiple join tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables:

Table `Position`:

```
KodePosition | NamePosition | UserLogin
========================================
0037           Master A       winz\alfa
0038           Master B        winz\beta
0043           Master C        winz\carlie
```

Table `UserBackup` (PJS):

```
KodePosition | UserOrigin | UserChange | StartDate | EndDate
================================================================
0037           winz\alfa    winz\carlie  10-10-2014  17-10-2014
```

Table `History`:

```
IdHistory | KodePosition | StartDate | EndDate    | User       | Comment
===============================================================================
19F5FCFC   0038            14-10-2014   14-10-2014  winz\beta     i not agree...
19F5FCFC   0043            15-10-2014   15-10-2014  winz\carlie   i agree...
```

I want to display data like this :

```
Name       |    Date     | Position | Comment
===================================================
winz\beta    14-10-2014    Master B   i not agree...
winz\carlie  15-10-2014    Master A   i agree...
```

Description :

- please note the data in Table UserBackup(PJS).
- if StartDate in Table History between StartDate and EndDate in Table UserBackup(PJS) and also the same UserChange with user, and then get NamePosition from Table Position by KodePosition of Table UserBackup(PJS).

For now, I have a stored procedure like this, but doesn't display the data I need.

```
select 
    A.IdHistory, A.StartDate, B.NamePosition, B.UserLogin, A.Comment
from 
    History as A
left join 
    Position as B on A.KodePosition = B.KodePosition
Where 
    A.IdHistory = '19F5FCFC'
order by 
    A.StartDate asc
```

Please help me guys... Thanks...

Comment: What's wrong with the current query you have? What does it produce?

Comment: The query does not show nameposition based kodeposition of table 'Table UserBackup (PJS)'. please note the description. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask three tables, you can do it like this (sorry for not using your data, but I dont understand the connections of them(or your explanations)).

```
SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2, b.Column1
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.Column1=b.Column1
WHERE (
  SELECT c.Column1
  FROM table3 AS c
  INNER JOIN table2 as b
  ON b.Column1=c.Column1
  WHERE c.Column2 LIKE 'MyTarget%');
```

You got to think in two SELECTs, dont try to put everything in one. Btw. most DBs dont support multi Joins.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what you are trying to do, this is a little bit of a stab in the dark...but based on your description, I believe you are trying to first filter the rows in the UserBackup(PJS) table based on whether the corresponding History.KodePosition record falls within the StartDate and EndDate of the corresponding UserBackup(PJS) record. Then, based on the returned KodePositions, you want to retrieve the related records from the Position table. I'm not sure this is the complete picture of what you are looking for, but hopefully this gets you further along:

```
;WITH cteData 
AS (
SELECT  u.KodePosition, h.IDHistory, h.StartDate, h.Comment
FROM UserBackup(PJS) u
INNER JOIN History h ON h.User = u.UserChange AND (h.StartDate >= u.Startdate and h.StartDate <= u.EndDate) 
)

SELECT c.IDHistory, c.StartDate, p.NamePostition, p.UserLogin, c.Comment
FROM Position p 
INNER JOIN cteData c ON c.KodePosition = p.KodePosition
```

Comment: result: | 19F5FCFC 15-10-2014 | Master A | winz\alfa | i agree... |

from result with your query, i get 'NamePosition' when i want. but i have a two problems.

just one row, must be two row display.
'UserLogin' display must be 'winz\carlie'.

Comment: Without being able to look more closely at your data, I'm not sure I can give you a specific solution. I would suggest first pulling out and running the query that is within the CTE to see if that encompasses all of the results you are looking for. If it does, then you may need to adjust how the second query (in the SELECT) is joining or filtering. If it doesn't then you probably need to adjust the query within the CTE to cast a wider net. Remember, this is just one way of querying your data - I have no doubt there are other paths you could take. Use this as a starting point.